# Get the name of the uploaded file

Tags: 6

I'm completely new in using drupal 6. I was wondering if there is a way to print the name of an uploaded file in a node. Thanks for the help

Cheers

Comment: Uploaded how, exactly? And how do you connect files to nodes? If via CCK, it should simply work.

Comment: How can I do that? i need it to automatically rename the image after it uploads and then print the name as well on the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@blankturd

You can add Custom field in the content type for uploading image to your node.

For that perform the below mentioned steps:

1) Go to the content type to which you want to have image upload field.

2) Click on the "Manage fields" tab

3) Then Add Label of the field name Ex, "Image" And machine Readable name like "field_image" then from the Dropdown select "File" as a controll type and last select "File Upload" widget.

By this way you can have an image upload field in your content type.

Now For displaying the image name which is uploaded there is many ways.

1) You can create new template file for the specific content type. Ex, page-CONTENT TYPE NAME.tpl.php and print the field directly.

2) You can create view for this purpose.

Hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get any node data (it loads all fields image or text), you can use **node_load** function

**function [node_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/6)**

```
Load a node object from the database
```

try from devel/php by loading any node by calling `print_r( node_load(1) );`

now you able to fetch your uploaded image data from node object.

**or**

if you want to fetch any node related data while creating node, use form alters & do custom submitting handler 
please refer this [link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6)

Comment: I used noad load, but I would like to 1: upload the file, 2: after upload, show the name and have the file renamed automatically.

Comment: tell me you want file name after node created or while node creating (means before creating node)??

Comment: file name before node creation if possible

Comment: While you uploading file through cck, it will upload the file and returns all the details including preview also.

Comment: how can I call the file name in a form field? text input